# SSIS Data Flow Architecture

Tags: ssis, google-cloud-dataflow

This might seem like an obvious answer, but I would like to confirm.
If we have an SSIS package (2016 or 2019) that moves data from database A to database B does the data move through the SSIS Server.
In other words, does the data flow directly from source database A to destination database B, or does it go from source database A to SSIS server, to destination database B?

Comment: Hi @James, Can you check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) ? Are you using Google Cloud Dataflow or just Data Flow ?

Answer (score 0):

"It depends!"

## All in one

Server A contains Database A1 and B1 and the SSIS package executes on Server A. No network is involved. The data will still need to be extracted from disk/memory pages in SQL Server, brought into the SSIS executable's memory, processed and written to memory/disk. Assuming you're using an element that requires data be brought into the SSIS space, like a Data Flow task. If your package was just Execute SQL Tasks, then the data never leaves SQL Server's boundaries.

## Two servers

Server A contains Database A1, server B contains Database B1 and the SSIS package executes on Server A (or B). You're now paying network latency as the data must exit A and travel to B for storing (and processing happens on either side).

## Two servers C&C

Server A contains Database A1 and Database B1 and the SSIS package executes on Server B. This will sometimes be referred to a Command and Control setup. You're now paying for double! network latency as a Data Flow Task must stream all source data from A1 to the server for processing and then once we're ready to write, we get to stream all that data back to the starting server. And pay for licensing the server for SSIS - because scale out isn't free.

## Three servers C&C

This set up is for when you absolutely want to eat the most in egress/ingress charges or you really want to see if the network jockeys have done their jobs. Server A contains Database A1, Server B contains Database B1 and the SSIS package executes on Server C. Now you pay network penalty to stream the data all about your data center as well as paying for 3 SQL Server licenses (A, B and C)

Comment: I should have been more specific, the scenario I have is Server A has database A1, Server B has database B1 and the SSIS executes on Server C.

Comment: Does the "Three servers C&C" section answer your question then? A data flow task will pull data across the network from A to C and then push processed data from C to B